# Probability of choosing subset of already previous chosen unique objects over time

Tags: probability, combinations

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244701/probability-of-choosing-same-set-of-unique-objects-over-time-without-replacement) I asked about the chance of choosing the same unique objects over time without replacement, and it reduced to the Birthday Problem (collision probability).

But I realized after that the question I really wanted to answer was:

What is the probability that the unique objects I choose in a round are a subset of all the unique objects I've chosen in previous rounds?

From my computer simulation it seems this is much more likely, with a collision by the 240th round with 4096 unique objects and choosing 8 per round. Intuitively to me this seems quite early, but there could be an error in my simulation.

Comment: Would the geometric distribution apply? I work out the chance an object would get chosen in each round is 0.000976562, and so the expected number of trials is ~1024. The median is ~709, so would it be reasonable to say that we could expect around 6.3% chance (.5^4) of collision after 709 rounds?

Comment: The geometric distribution does not apply here, because the probability of success varies from draw to draw.

Comment: @awkward I don't understand how the probability of seeing an object changes, it's independent per round isn't it? I calculate the probability by (1 - the chance of not seeing it).

Comment: The number of previously-seen objects increases over time, so the chance of success increases.

Comment: @awkward But the geometric cumulative function assumes that doesn't it?

Comment: @awkward I understand now: the geometric distribution assumes each round is independent from any other.

Comment: For a geometric distribution, the cumulative distribution is increasing (as it is for all distributions), but the chance of success on any one trial is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restate the question, we have 4096 objects, and we draw 8 objects at a time, without replacement.  After each draw the 8 objects are replaced.  We would like to know the probability that on the nth draw all 8 objects have been previously drawn.

In order to simplify notation, let's suppose that on the nth draw, the objects drawn are numbers 1 through 8.  Let's say the nth draw has "property $i$" if object $i$ has not been drawn in any of the previous $n-1$ draws, for $i=1,2,3,\dots,8$.  We will use the Principle of Inclusion / Exclusion (PIE) to compute the probability that the final draw has none of the properties, i.e. all of the objects $1,2,3, \dots ,8$ have been previously drawn.  Let $S_i$ be the total probability that the final draw has $i$ of the properties, for $i=1,2,3, \dots ,8$.  Then
$$\begin{align}
S_1 &= \binom{8}{1} \left( \frac{\binom{4095}{8}}{\binom{4096}{8}} \right)^{n-1} \\
S_2 &= \binom{8}{2} \left( \frac{\binom{4094}{8}}{\binom{4096}{8}} \right)^{n-1} \\S_3 &= \binom{8}{3} \left( \frac{\binom{4093}{8}}{\binom{4096}{8}} \right)^{n-1} \\
&\dots \\
S_8 &= \binom{8}{8} \left( \frac{\binom{4088}{8}}{\binom{4096}{8}} \right)^{n-1} 
\end{align}$$
By PIE, the probability that all  8 objects have been previously drawn is
$$p_n = 1 - S_1 + S_2 - S_3 + \dots +S_8$$
If we define a "success" as a draw in which all the objects drawn have been previously drawn, then the probability of a success on the 240th draw is
$p_{240} = 0.000373546$, and the expected number of successes in draws 2 through 240 is 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{240} p_n = 0.0121255$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it normal for S_i to be larger than 1?

Comment: It's mind expanding to imagine the PIE in action in this example. This has been extremely helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Tom, Yes, S_i may be larger than one.